# Using nuget within VS solution with only database dbproj projects to reference other dbproj files

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget, dbproj

So I have a Visual Studio solution which contains 3 database (.dbproj) projects.  These projects need to reference other sql projects from other solutions, which I have packaged and uploaded to nuget.  How can I manage these external packages / references in Visual Studio within the dbproj's?

Right clicking the database project within visual studio doesn't give me the "Manage NuGet Packages..." option.

I can Manage NuGet Packages for Solution to at least download the required packages to the solution root but at the project level, where the references are required I'd have to manually manage the references within each projects' references and update manually any time the package is updated so the reference points to the correct versioned package directory.

Is there a better way to do this for dbproj references for database projects in Visual Studio??

Answer (score 3):

I ended up following the same path, creating NuGet packages of the referenced databases and then manually (via command line) installing them at the standard \package location.  Then correcting the database references manually in the IDE

There is a [work item for this functionality](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2439), go vote it up.  There is a fork of the functionality already developed that sounds like it is fairly feature complete.  You might try it out.

Comment: I took a similar approach, but instead of copying the files manually I added them to the database projects as links (Add exiting item, then use the Add As Link button).